# projective curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, projective-geometry, projective-space

In *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves* (Silverman, Tate), they introduce projective curves and then state:

> The intuition to keep in mind: an affine curve is somehow "missing" some points that lie out at infinity and the points that are missing are the limiting directions as one moves along the curve toward infinity. (pg. 272)

I was wondering, doesn't this mean that all the curves have to converge as they approach infinity? Because we can graph function in $R^2$ that don't converge (e.g. trig functions), so how could there be a "limiting tangent direction"?

Comment: What do you mean by converge? Also you should be careful taking too much intuition from real analysis --- trigonometric functions are not "curves" in algebraic geometry, and curve means something very different in Silverman/Tate than it does in an analysis setting.

Comment: by converge, I mean the curves can't be changing direction constantly/everywhere, or it wouldn't make sense to "plug in" a point at infinity.

Comment: Yeah so you could think about plane curves, say $V(y - x^2) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2$. If we were to graph this normally, we would see that as the curve tends off to infinity, its slope gets closer and closer to vertical. Projectivizing the plane, that means that the two ends of the parabola meet at a point at infinity, and hence the projectivization of this curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ looks like a circle. So you will definitely have these "limiting tangent directions."

Comment: So, is it true that as every algebraic curve tends to infinty, if we graphed it normally its slope would tend to a fixed value? Or does that question not make sense with algebraic curves?

Comment: An asymptote to an algebraic curve at $\infty$ in the real plane is its tangent  at $\infty$. The parabola $y-x^2$ has no asymtote, but an asymptotic direction (vertical) which means that it passes though the point at $\infty$ on the $y$-axis and the tangent at $\infty$ is the line at $\infty$.